# CSS - Fill with set proportions

Tags: css

I was wondering whether it is possible in CSS to fill a div with a (unknown) amount of divs. They should fill with each the same width.

In Android, this is known as "layout-weight". My question, is something like this available in CSS? Or do I have to use Javascript/jQuery for this?

Thanks in advance,
Bart

Comment: Why do you need to fill a div with multiple divs to simulate layout_weight? You can use percentage width to do the same.

Comment: But when the amount of div's is unknown, it isn't a possibility. When I set the width of Div A to 50%, and there is no Div B, then the parent is not completely filled.

Comment: So do you need to have the full width of parent divided to unknown number of divs?

Comment: Exactly. That is what I want to do.

Comment: You can do that with CSS Flexbox. Wait till I give you an example.

Comment: Perfect, I will wait for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wjaedd9d/

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
    .parent .child {
        flex: 1;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Some content</div>
    <div class="child">Some content</div>
    <div class="child">Some content</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Try increasing the number of child divs.

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect! I will accept in within 2 minutes (can't do it earlier)!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
display: flexbox
flex-direction: row;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/terda12/1ug7Lmyf/2/)